# Date Format Modifcation in List

Tags: 2013, list, column, validation, calculated-column-formula

I would like to format a new column with the Month and Day of another column. Is there a way to accomplish this? I tried adding this `=TEXT([Date of Birth],"MM/DD")` in column validation but it gives me the following error.

> The formula cannot refer to another column.  Check the formula for
>   spelling mistakes or update the formula to reference only this column.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to get the month and day components separately and combine, something like:

```
=CONCATENATE(MONTH([Date of Birth), "/", DAY([Date of Birth]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put the formula?  The TEXT() function should work fine in a calculated column but you would get the error you indicate in the default value of a field.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. I figured out the issue, I didn't make the new column a calculated column. Duh!